# How to prove that $ \phi: K^n \to Spm K[X_1,...,X_n]$ is injective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, maximal-and-prime-ideals

This question was left as an exercise in my class of Algebraic Geometry and I am not able to think about it. So, I am posting it here hoping to get some help.

> Question : Let K=L be two algebraically closed fields then show that the map $ \phi: K^n \to Spm  K[x_1,...,x_n]$ is injective ( ie $\phi $ is a map from $a=(a_1,...,a_n) \to M_a =<x_1- a_1,...,x_n -a_n>$)

Let $M_a =M_b$ ie $<x_1- a_1,...,x_n -a_n>= <x_1 -b_1,...,x_n -b_n>$ = > $k_1 (x_1- a_1) +... + k_n (x_n -a_n) = k'_1 (x_1- b_1) +...+ k'_n (x_n - b_n)$. But I am not able to think how should I get a=b from this. Can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $a = (a_1,\dotsc,a_n) \in K^n$ there is an evaluation ring homomorphism $e_a\colon K[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]\to K$ mapping $x_i\mapsto a_i$ and with $\ker(e_a) = M_a = \langle x_1-a_1, \dotsc, x_n-a_n\rangle$.

Now, let $a,b\in K^n$ and assume $M_a = M_b$. Then $x_i-a_i \in M_b = \ker(e_b)$, which means $b_i-a_i = e_b(x_i-a_i) = 0$, i.e., $a_i = b_i$, for all $i$. This implies $a=b$.